# How to sum between two valor in excel?

Tags: excel

I have this data in excel:

sale x time:
[image: sale x time]

How do you get the maximum sum between values between zero with a formula? For example, in the first row 2 or 3 in the second row. In other words, how to get the sum between equal and consecutive values with excel

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is very difficult to do with a single formula. You add helper cells or use VBA if either is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution

```
Function MyMax(r As Range)
Dim elem As Variant
Dim sum, v, max As Double
sum = 0
max = 0
For Each elem In r
    v = elem.Value
    sum = sum + v
    If v = 0 Then
        If sum > max Then max = sum
        sum = 0
    End If
Next elem
If sum > max Then max = sum
MyMax = max
End Function
```

[image]

**Edit**

A single-cell formula would look something like this (for the particular case of 8 months):

```
=MAX(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2,0,ROW($A$1:$H$8),1,COLUMN($A$1:$H$8)))*(ROW($A$1:$H$8)+COLUMN($A$1:$H$8)<=9)*(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B2,0,ROW($A$1:$H$8),1,COLUMN($A$1:$H$8)),0)=0))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

This considers all sub-arrays of C2:J2, sums them and tests if they contain a zero. All the references to the 2-dimensional array $A$1:$H$8 would need generalising with Indirect and Address for different ranges so it would be a long formula using volatile functions - probably VBA is preferable unless anyone knows of a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

I try it with a single formula, but no way. Assuming that your CODE column is column A... So CODE is located in cell A1
Add:

Column K:

`{=K.ESIMO.MENOR(SI($C$2:$J$2=0;COLUMNA($C$2:$J$2)-COLUMNA($C$2)+1);1)}` (Spanish)
`{=SMALL(IF($C$2:$J$2=0,COLUMN($C$2:$J$2)-COLUMN($C$2)+1),1)}` (English)

Column L:

`{=K.ESIMO.MENOR(SI($C$2:$J$2=0;COLUMNA($C$2:$J$2)-COLUMNA($C$2)+1);2)}` (Spanish)
          `{=SMALL(IF($C$2:$J$2=0,COLUMN($C$2:$J$2)-COLUMN($C$2)+1),2)}` (English)

Column L:

`=SUMA(DESREF(B2;0;K2;1;L2-K2-1))` (Spanish)

`=SUM(DESREF(B2,0,K2,1,L2-K2-1))` (English)

As the formulas on columns K and L are matricial, when your write it, without the brackets ({}), you should press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to get the matricial function working.
That one is setup to look for the "0" value, as you ask, if you are looking for another one, change the formula on "`$C$2:$J$2=0`".

If that is not your distribution (Cell A1 => CODE) then shift the values.

This formulas can be drag and it will work in your book.

Hope it helps